# Antlr 4.7 no longer generates errorNodes for input at the end of an inputstream

Tags: antlr, antlr4

I have a simple grammar like so:

```
grammar Test;
generator : expression;

expression
    : NUMBER                         # Number
    | ID                             # String
    | expression '+' expression      # Add
    ;

NUMBER: [0-9]+ [0-9]*;
ID : [a-zA-Z_]+ [a-zA-Z0-9_]* ;
```

I want the expression `5xx` to be considered an error (since it should be `5+xx` or `5` or `xx`). With Antlr 4.6 this would happen, but with antlr 4.7 this doesn't happen.

Here's my full test:

```
    @Test()
    public void doATest() {
        TestLexer lexer = new TestLexer(new ANTLRInputStream("5xx"));
        TestParser parser = new TestParser(new CommonTokenStream(lexer));

        //Walk the tree and throw if there are any error nodes.
        ParseTreeWalker.DEFAULT.walk(new TestBaseListener() {
            @Override public void visitErrorNode(ErrorNode node) {
                //Throws with 4.6, not with 4.7
                throw new RuntimeException("Hit error node: " + node);
            }
        }, parser.generator());
    }
```

The other odd observation I have is that including the `expression '+' expression` rule is important, without this 4.6 won't generate an error either.

Is there some special flag that I need to set somewhere to indicate that an input stream should be exactly one generator and not have any trailing tokens?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there some special flag that I need to set somewhere to indicate that an input stream should be exactly one generator and not have any trailing tokens?

Yes, that's exactly what the `EOF` token does:

```
generator : expression EOF;
```

This way you'll always get an error on extra tokens, regardless of the version of ANTLR or whether or not you include the `expression '+' expression` rule.

Comment: OMG thanks! You won't believe how much time I sank into this :p